# Triggers: Instead of / For Insert, which will trigger first?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to understand a Document of stored procedures and triggers where it inserts and updates a table with a trigger.

They gave me 2 trigger documents and there are two triggers for this particular table:

trig_table_ii and trig_table_ti.

- trig_table_ii : instead of insert
- trig_table_ti : for insert

Which will trigger first when table is inserted/updated?

In trig_table_ii ( INSTEAD OF INSERT ) there is an INSERT Statement here for that same TABLE. Does that mean trig_table_ii executes first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None will fire when table is updated.
`FOR INSERT` is the same of `AFTER INSERT`. This will fire after you finish inserting a record.

`INSTEAD OF INSERT` will fire as a replacement of your insert. This trigger will ignore your original insert statement and execute whatever is there to execute.

Lets say in your `INSTEAD OF` tigger you, for some reason, do not insert the record. So, `FOR INSERT` trigger will not be fired.

Check here for more info: [CREATE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Comment: Hi, I figured that Instead of insert will fire first, just because there is a FINAL Insert in the end that could trigger the FOR INSERT. Is this correct? Thanks for the reference though I have read that but just wanted to ask this question which execs first.

Comment: `Instead of` will fire first because is literaly you saying "Don't insert now. Run this trigger first". If this trigger insert some records, then `For insert` is called